# Typescript in `file://` environment

Tags: javascript, html, typescript

Recently I just picked up Typescript for a personal project. **Since the project is designed to be ran locally (explicitly `file://`), I won't be able to use `import`/`export` features due to CORS restrictions.** Aware of another similarly written question but lacking the specific context on my use case, I pose these questions:

- How does one tell Typescript that all (or at least certain) scripts are imported to HTML via `<script type="text/javascript" src="./source.js">`?
- Does Typescript's `tsc` build projects with this in mind? Also, does it edit existing HTML files to take this into consideration too? If not, are there tools to automate this process as well?
- I don't want to bundle them like `webpack` or `tsc-bundle` does, since a secondary objective to this project is to keep all `.js` files human-readable just as much as the `.ts` files do.

Building Typescript using `tsc -p tsconfig.json`, configured to `"target" : "ES2015"` and `"module" : "None"`, only outputs their respective `.js` files and doesn't update any of the HTML's `<script>` includes. Am currently maintaining the html file by manually inserting and juggling any new modules that emerges over the course of development.
My current load order in `index.html` is as follows:

- `index.js` handles UI controls and loads first.
- The remaining pseudo-modules `.js` files loads in-between, since these only define classes and doesn't perform any operations, so I figured it's safe to load them here.
- `main.js` handles all the code from javascript "modules" and loads last.

My main concern is that my in-between modules might load out of order due to human error.

Edit: Running a local webserver is out of the question too, since the project is meant to target audience with limited technical knowledge, with the `index.html` file the only file they need to run in their browser.

Comment: `tsc` does not edit or compile HTML files. If you run into the problem that typescript does not recognise code from other files that are loaded via a script tag, then maybe you could create a `.d.ts` file that contains all your type definitions? Btw, why would you want to run from a `file://` environment? It's quite unsafe and also not necessary even if you want to run a local project on a local machine.

Comment: @Kokodoko
The `file://` specification is because I wish for it to actually be an offline-capable game; yes, a game like one of those HTML5 CYOA engines (Twine, Undum, etc.)
I figured that a JS-backed HTML file would be most compatible to most people's devices. Running a local server is out of the question too, since I also intend to target non-tech-savvy people as my audience as well.

Comment: For that kind of problem you could create a "kiosk" app which is just a chromium browser that will open your files automatically for those users. The app will have the correct permissions and can even run a server if that's necessary. The non-tech-savvy user just has to open the browser like they normally would. You could look at NWJS or Electron for this. https://nwjs.io , https://www.electronjs.org

Comment: Ah hey, I've thought of that already too. Was considering it as some sort of last resort honestly. Thanks for your alternative, although do they also support releases for multiple platforms? (Windows and Android, specifically)